# Compare-Object Returning Invalid Results

Tags: arrays, powershell, compare, compareobject

First post to stackoverflow so apologies in advance if I miss a social norm.

I have an array in PowerShell that holds thousands of objects in it. Standard stuff with each object having properties such as username, login times, computer they logged into, etc. I then split off a small number of objects from the first array with users whose name starts with A:

```
$Array2 = $Array1 | where-object Username -like '*\a*'
```

This works as expected.

I want to build a third array that only contains the objects from $Array1 that are not in $Array2. Or in other words an array with only users whose usernames do not start with A.
This seems like the way to go:

```
$Array3 = compare-object $Array1 $Array2 | select-object -expandproperty InputObject
```

Expectation:

```
$Array3 | where-object Username -like '*\a*'
```

results in a nothing returned

What I'm getting though are plenty of results. Strangely if I look at the .count of each array the math works out. Array1 minus Array2 equals Array3. So it is removing the correct number of objects, just not the expected objects. What am I doing wrong here? Since I'm doing a pull from the exact array I'm comparing against I can't think of any other criteria it would be searching for that would return an unexpected match. I also tried sorting each array by the same property before comparing because I was grasping but as expected that didn't fix it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're missing a dollar sign in front of array1:  `$Array2 = Array1 | where-object Username -like '*\a*'`.  I tried it out using get-aduser but with the name property, and it works for me.  I don't have a username property, or names with backslashes in them.  If you don't assign $array3, does the compare-object output look right?

Comment: There's only one backslash in the username right?  `dom/joe/abel`  Compare-object looks at the string version of the aduser object, or the DistinguishedName.  It's not looking at a username property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My conclusion is that some commandlets build arrays in such a way that it breaks compare-object. I'm still unsure as to what this mysterious "way" is, but the problem presents itself when using Citrix's Get-BrokerSession and does not when using Get-AdUser.

Long answer
For those really wanting to use compare-object here is the way I got it to work:

`compare-object $Array1 $Array2 -Property Username -PassThru`

With the -PassThru being the eureka moment for me.

My question was specifically about how/why compare-object wasn't working the way I expected. All answers, to my interpretation, only provided different ways to work around the problem and didn't actually answer the question. Special thanks to @js2010 for continuing to work with me through it.

Answer (score 2):

The simple way is to do the same `-like` assignment but with the opposite operator `-notlike` e.g.:

```
$Array2 = $Array1 | where-object Username -like 'a*'
$Array3 = $Array1 | where-object Username -notlike 'a*'
```

Note:

(not sure if it was a typo in the question for the match: `'*\a*'`), The match should be `a*` with only a single asterix after the "`a`" character. You want to match everything *starting* with "`a`" and "`*`" for anything after (e.g. only match "Alex", and not "Brad").

Comment: Sorry I should have explained that as it does indeed look like a typo. the  ```*\``` is because I'm dealing with multiple domains in my username property. So I'm grabbing domain1\a* and domain2\a* users.

Answer (score 2):

Compare object works in a funny way.  With objects, you usually need to specify the properties.  I'm surprised the docs don't have an example of this.  Unfortunately, -property doesn't take wildcards.  I think without "-property", unless there's a special compareto() or equals() method, it will compare the string versions of the objects.  I think with get-aduser output, it will compare strings (distinguishedname's).

```
$a = @([pscustomobject]@{name='joe'})              
$b = @([pscustomobject]@{name='joey'})

compare-object $a $b  # no output, they're equal!


compare-object $a $b -property name

name SideIndicator
---- -------------
joey =>
joe  <=
```

Trying out datetime's.  It uses something besides strings to compare.

```
$a = get-date; sleep -Milli 500; $b = get-date
$a.tostring(); $b.tostring()
4/23/2020 6:33:56 PM
4/23/2020 6:33:56 PM

$a -eq $b
False

compare-object $a $b

InputObject          SideIndicator
-----------          -------------
4/23/2020 6:33:56 PM =>
4/23/2020 6:33:56 PM <=
```

Comment: But if I'm pulling the object directly from the first array every property should be same. It is obviously comparing the two arrays and successfully working out how many are different between the two. So doesn't that prove it can compare objects not just properties?

Comment: I don't see that unless the string versions of the objects are different.  Can you provide an example?

Comment: I'm not sure how to build an example others could try without access to my data. If I can recreate it with get-aduser would you be able to recreate on your side?

Comment: Even with get-aduser, all compare-object is doing is running $obj.tostring() on each object, and then comparing strings.

Comment: Someone told me compare-object might try a .compareto() or .equals() method first, before resorting to .tostring().  But aduser objects don't have compareto's.  Datetime's do.

Comment: My bad.  aduser objects have an equals() method.  Hmm, I'm not sure it's specific to that type.  I can set enabled to false in one of them, and compare-object will still say they're equal.

Comment: Using Get-ADUser worked for me as well. It must be in the way the Citrix cmdlet get-brokersession builds the array objects. I'm going to let this go with the conclusion that some cmdlets build arrays in an incompatible way with how compare-object works and move on with life. Thanks for sticking with me through my confusion!

Comment: Ok.  If would have helped if you said what commands you were using.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by negating the `Where-Object` operand (`-notlike` instead of `-like`):

```bsh
$Array2 = $Array1 |Where-Object Username -like *\a*
$Array3 = $Array1 |Where-Object Username -notlike *\a*
```

... or, you can take advantage of the `.Where()` extension method's "Split" mode, and do it in a single assignment:

```bsh
$Array2,$Array3 = $Array1.Where({$_.Username -like '*\a*'}, 'Split')
```

Comment: That first example works for me.  You're missing quotes:  `{$_ -like 'a*'}`

Comment: I feel this comes close to explaining it but I think the failing is on my side. If I'm understanding you correctly, the math part doesn't match what I'm seeing. In your example $Array1.count would be six, $Array2.count would be two, and comparing the two the objects that are different (your middle row) would result in a count of five no matches. But what I am seeing is that $Array1.count minus $Array2.count comes up as four not five. I'm still missing something in how this works.

Comment: So after some trial and error this worked: 'compare-object $Array1 $Array2 -Property Username -PassThru' though I still don't know why, which is troubling.

Comment: No, my explanation was completely off, it makes sense that it'd work with `-Property Username`

Comment: Wish it did for me!  Thanks anyway for the attempted explanation. I'm not going to mark any of these so far as the answer though as my question is about why compare-object isn't working like I think it should and not how to build a different solution to get what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I think `Compare-Object` internally uses the `ToString()` method to compare objects.

```
class foo {
    [string]$str

    foo($str) {
        $this.str = $str
    }
}

class bar {
    [string]$str

    bar($str) {
        $this.str = $str
    }

    [string] ToString() { return $this.str }
}

"== Compare foo object =="
$fooA = [foo]::new("a")
$fooB = [foo]::new("b")
compare $fooA $fooB -IncludeEqual | ft

"== Compare bar object =="
$barA = [bar]::new("a")
$barB = [bar]::new("b")
compare $barA $barB -IncludeEqual | ft
```

output:

```
== Compare foo object ==

InputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
foo         ==           


== Compare bar object ==

InputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
b           =>           
a           <=
```

Comment: Yep.  That's what the process object example in the docs does.

Comment: This might answer my question but I'm not a strong enough PowerShell guy to go from someone explaining how the engine works to knowing why my car won't start. ELI 5 it?